# flutter not compiling with different colored border sides

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting started with flutter and want to create a widget which has different colored borders on each side depending on a condition.

```
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
 border: new Border(
  top: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.red),
  left: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.red),
  right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.red),
  bottom: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white)
 ),
 borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
  topLeft: new Radius.circular(15.0)
 ),
),
```

whenever I try to use more than one color on the borders in breaks and I'm not sure why but works fine if they all are one single color.

I get the following error on the hot reload :

```
I/flutter ( 1274): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderDecoratedBox#746f5 relayoutBoundary=up5:
I/flutter ( 1274):   creator: DecoratedBox ← Container ← Row ← Column ← Container ← Column ← Center ← MediaQuery ←
I/flutter ( 1274):     LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 1274):   parentData: offset=Offset(140.2, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
I/flutter ( 1274):   constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
I/flutter ( 1274):   size: Size(57.0, 38.0)
I/flutter ( 1274):   decoration: BoxDecoration:
I/flutter ( 1274):     border: Border(top: BorderSide(MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xfff44336)), 1.0,
I/flutter ( 1274):       BorderStyle.solid), right: BorderSide(MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff4caf50)), 1.0,
I/flutter ( 1274):       BorderStyle.solid), bottom: BorderSide(MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff4caf50)), 1.0,
I/flutter ( 1274):       BorderStyle.solid), left: BorderSide(MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xfff44336)), 1.0,
I/flutter ( 1274):       BorderStyle.solid))
I/flutter ( 1274):     borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0))
I/flutter ( 1274):   configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#bb4b7(), devicePixelRatio: 2.6,
I/flutter ( 1274):     locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
I/flutter ( 1274): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter ( 1274):     child: RenderPadding#f05f1 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1274):       child: RenderParagraph#4842a relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1274):         text: TextSpan
```

thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That gives you the following error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
I/flutter (19471): A borderRadius can only be given for uniform borders.
```

So, if you want to have different border colors, better use a Material:

```
Material(
          child: Container(),
          shape: Border(
            right: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            left: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            bottom: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            top: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```